# SQL/HSQLDB query and sub-query in Aggregate Function

Tags: sql, hsqldb

My database looks like this (very simple) and is called "RideDate":
  BikeDate Bike Miles
What I am looking to achieve is a query that for each month is a total(Sum) across all years, average(Avg) across all years, and a total for a specific year
 (WHERE YEAR("Date")= '2014"). (I don"t have my exact code in front of me due to power fluctuations, pushing me onto an iPad (high winds and wet/heavy snow)).

My attempt goes something like this:

```
SElECT MONTH("BikeDate") AS "Month", SUM("Miles") AS "SMiles", AVG("AMiles") AS "Average",
(SELECT MONTH("BikeDate") SUM("Miles") WHERE YEAR("BikeDate") = '2014') AS "2014"
FROM "RideDate"
GROUP BY MONTH("BikeDate")
ORDER BY MONTH("BikeDate") ASC
```

The results should be:
(month) (sum of month over all years) (avg of month over all years) (sum of month for '14)

The last column will not collate by the 'group by month' and gives a sum for the whole year.

How can I write the sub-query to sum across the iterated month of the main query for the selected year? Is there another way of solving this?

Comment: Which error do you get when you run the query you wrote ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try it with a `CROSS JOIN`

```
SELECT * FROM
(
(SELECT MONTH("BikeDate") AS "Month", SUM("Miles") AS "SMiles", AVG("AMiles") AS "Average",
FROM "RideDate"
GROUP BY MONTH("BikeDate"))a
CROSS JOIN 
(SELECT SUM("Miles") as "YearSum"
FROM "RideDate"
WHERE YEAR("BikeDate") = '2014')b
) results
```